# DocuSign Admin API OpenAPI / SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign eSignature API, and am generating client code with the help of the openapi codegen (via these https://github.com/docusign/OpenAPI-Specifications).

Now I have to use the DocuSign Manage API (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/), too, but I can't find any Swagger / OpenAPI definition for that?

Is it somewhere hidden, does it not exists, and are there plans to make it available at one point? Are there any other options, SDKs, anything or do I have to make these calls "manually"?

Comment: We expect to have this sometimes in the summer. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Swagger file for the Admin API is not yet available.
That's also why DocuSign doesn't yet have SDKs for the API yet.
I don't have access to any scheduling information on it.

I suggest that you handle any Admin API calls you need to do manually for now.

What language are you creating SDKs for with CodeGen? (Please answer in a comment or by editing your original question.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using PHP. I only need one call (to create a user via admin) so that's no problem.